# Function to split array by number not working

Tags: java

I have to execute a function `splitArrayByNum` that will be given a array of integers and an integer delimiter that will split the array using the delimiter. This function will return 2D arrays: For example, `splitArrayByNum([0,0,0,3,1,1,1], 3) -> [[0,0,0],[1,1,1]]` and `splitArrayByNum([3,1,3,3], 3) ->[[1]]`.

Why does my code not print anything to the console?

```
package hw3;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayUtils {

    public static void p(int[][] a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a[i]));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         int[] x1={0,0,0,3,1,1,1}; int y1=3;
         splitArrayByNum(x1, y1);
         p(splitArrayByNum(x1, y1));
    }

    public static int lastIndexOf(int value, int[] nums) {
        for (int i = nums.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
            if (nums[i] == value) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public static int firstIndexOf(int value, int[] nums) {
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i] == value) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
   \\ turns the number of elements between two Extreme instances
    public static int mySpan(int value, int[] nums) {
        if (lastIndexOf(value, nums)==-1)
            return 0;
        else
            return lastIndexOf(value, nums) - firstIndexOf(value, nums) + 1;
    }
    public static int [][] splitArrayByNum(int[]input,int number){
        //finding the'm' in 'arraySplit[m][]'
        int []arrayInUse=new int[input.length];
        arrayInUse=Arrays.copyOfRange(input, 0, input.length);
        int counter=0;
        while(mySpan(number,arrayInUse)!=0)
        {
            int first=arrayInUse[firstIndexOf(number,arrayInUse)];
            int last= arrayInUse[lastIndexOf(number,arrayInUse)];
            int k=1;
            int m=mySpan(number,arrayInUse);
            while (m>0)
            {        \\ checking for deleting sequences  from the sides 

                if( (arrayInUse[first]!=arrayInUse[first+k]) &&(arrayInUse[last]!=arrayInUse[last-k]))
                    continue;
                if (arrayInUse[first]==arrayInUse[first+k])
                    m=m-1;
                if(m<0)
                    continue;
                first=first+k;
                if ((arrayInUse[last])==(arrayInUse[last-k]))
                    m=m-2;
                if(m<0)
                    continue;
                last=last-k;
                k=k+1;

            }
            if (m<0)
                continue;
            counter=counter+1;
            arrayInUse=Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayInUse, first, last+1);
        }
        int [][]splitArray=new int[counter][];
        // creating splitArray
        counter=0;
        arrayInUse=Arrays.copyOfRange(input, 0, input.length);
        while(mySpan(number,arrayInUse)!=0)
        {
            int first=arrayInUse[firstIndexOf(number,arrayInUse)];
            int last= arrayInUse[lastIndexOf(number,arrayInUse)];
            int k=1;
            int m=mySpan(number,arrayInUse);
            while (m>0)
            {        \\ checking for deleting sequences  from the sides 
                if( (arrayInUse[first]!=arrayInUse[first+k]) &&(arrayInUse[last]!=arrayInUse[last-k]))
                    continue;
                if (arrayInUse[first]==arrayInUse[first+k])
                    m=m-1;
                if(m<0)
                    continue;
                first=first+k;
                if ((arrayInUse[last])==(arrayInUse[last-k]))
                    m=m-2;
                if(m<0)
                    continue;
                last=last-k;
                k=k+1;

            }
            if (m<0)
                continue;

            arrayInUse = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayInUse, first+1, last+1);
            splitArray[counter] = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayInUse,first+1,firstIndexOf(number,arrayInUse));
            counter = counter+1;
        }

        return splitArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "my code didn't response when I was running it, why?" mean?

Comment: can you please narrow down codea little bit ? this is almost code-dump

Comment: I was excepting from "int[] x1={0,0,0,3,1,1,1}; int y1=3;" to give back [[0,0,0],[1,1,1]] however when I "run" it didn't turn back anything

Comment: This code doesn't even compile!!! Fix your compilation errors first!

Comment: mySpan- turns the number of elements between to extreme instances. splitArrayByNum at the first part checks for the length  of the returning array and at the second part the array is created

Comment: @ Fabian doesn't Eclipse automatically compile codes? because it didn't put any notifications to me, so it seems to compile

Comment: Your examples in your question don't match your API. For instance, "splitArrayByNum([0,0,0,3,1,1,1])" doesn't have a parameter for the delimiter. Also, what's with all the weird blank lines at the end of your code? Format your code properly and ask a proper question. Also, what did you see when you ran your code under the debugger? You did run it under the debugger, didn't you?

Comment: by "run it under the debugger" you mean being in debug mode and 
click on "run"... it didn't show a thing

Answer (score 0):

Your first block of `while (m>0)` never exits because your two conditionals that decrement `m` are never met.

```
        while (m>0)
        { 
            System.out.println(m); //Debugging statement to show that value of m never changes

            if( (arrayInUse[first]!=arrayInUse[first+k]) &&(arrayInUse[last]!=arrayInUse[last-k]))
                continue;
            if (arrayInUse[first]==arrayInUse[first+k])
                m=m-1;
            if(m<0)
                continue;
            first=first+k;
            if ((arrayInUse[last])==(arrayInUse[last-k]))
                m=m-2;
            if(m<0)
                continue;
            last=last-k;
            k=k+1;

        }
```

Comment: @ Forager, thank you!(to change "continue" into "break" will fix this problem but it still didn't work...) but how debug helps me? When I am in debug mode I'm clicking on run and it didn't show a thing

Comment: Debug mode will pause execution of a program when it hits a line you've set a breakpoint at. To do so, press Ctrl + Shift + B on the line in question. Or you could just add in print statements in places like I did, to see if the piece of code is running, or check on a variable's value